# Single out a td in a row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

It's brain dead me here again.

**Issue:**
trying to get the value of a hidden td in the same row as a selected button.  The code i have finds both the values of both hidden tds, i just want the value of the hidden td of the same row as the pressed button.

Thanks in advance

**HTML**

```
<tr>
    <td class="rowid" hidden>1</td>
    <td >data</td>
    <td ><button>process</button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="rowid" hidden>2</td>
    <td >data</td>
    <td ><button>process</button></td>
</tr>
```

**jQuery**

```
$j("Button").on("click",function(){     
    var strRwId = $j( "td.strRowId" ).text();
    $j("td.strRowId").css( "background-color", "red" );
    alert("you pressed the edit button for Row: " + strRwId + "!");
});
```

Comment: typo here- `<button>process</butoon>` ..see the clossing `</butoon>`

Comment: Awee come on now, that is minor, i was asking for help in the code, that will not fix  my issue if you correct the typo.

Comment: No No.. @Dewinky,, I just pointed out..just for you to fix it in the post..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this.

```js
$("button").on("click", function () {
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var strRwId = tr.find('.rowid').text();
    tr.css("background-color", "red");
    alert("you pressed the edit button for Row: " + strRwId + "!");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="rowid" hidden>1</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td><button>process</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="rowid" hidden>2</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td><button>process</button></td>
    </tr>   
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

this could give you an idea

```
$("button").click(function() {
   var $button = $(this);
   var $tr = $button.parent("tr");
   var $hidden = $tr.find("td[hidden]");
   alert("you pressed the edit button for Row: " + $hidden.html() + "!");
})
```